# System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception_WasThrown'

Tags: c#, asp.net, lib.web.mvc

Follow my code:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult StreamVideo(int type1, int type2)
{
    using (var ctx = new Entities())
    {
        var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Type1 == type1 && x.Type2 == type2).FirstOrDefault();

        byte[] video_byte = result.Video;

        return new RangeFileContentResult(video_byte, "video/x-msvideo", "NameFile.mp4", DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

I have a "modal bootstrap" where it has video content.When closing modal and opening again, it gives problem:

> System.OutOfMemoryException: 'Exception_WasThrown'

[image]

Problem occurs on line:

```
var result = ctx.Table.Where(x => x.Type1 == type1 && x.Type2 == type2).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any solution ?

Comment: What is being returned? How many bytes in the column(s)? I am going to guess that `Video` is a varbinary / image type field and you are storing GBs in that field.

Comment: How big is `result.Video`?  Maybe you are clobbering your [Large Object Heap](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/.net-framework/the-dangers-of-the-large-object-heap/).

Comment: " I am going to guess that Video is a varbinary "  Exactly

Comment: Have you tried `.AsNoTracking()` ? `ctx.Table.AsNoTracking().Where(....`

Comment: @bigtlb, Video has size of 98MB.

Comment: I'll try with ".AsNoTracking ()". Wait.

Comment: Now gives the same conversion problem, I'll edit post.

Comment: (*about your update*) This is completely different code. Your original post was about **retrieval**. The edited question is about **posting** (upload) of a file. If you have an additional question you should ask it as a new question, do not change your existing question and add an (mostly) unrelated problem to it.

Comment: Guys, can you guys help me? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811925/element-video-does-not-play-using-rangefilestreamresult  Based on the response of friend @bigtlb

Answer (score 1):

When retrieving large amounts of `varbinary` data you need to be careful that you don't overtax the Large Object Heap.  Consider retrieving the data as a stream instead.  `EntityCommand` and `SqlCommand` can both retrieve readers, and you can get a stream from them.

[SqlClient Streaming](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support)

```
using (connection)
{
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
      $"SELECT Video FROM Table where Type1={type1} and Type2={type2};",
      connection);
    connection.Open();

    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    reader.Read();
    var stream = reader.GetStream(0);

   ... Use the stream here...
}
```

Comment: I use https://github.com/tpeczek/Lib.Web.Mvc to play video.The line: `return new RangeFileContentResult(video_byte, "video/x-msvideo", "NameFile.mp4", DateTime.Now);` does not work ?

Comment: Try `public RangeFileStreamResult(Stream fileStream, string contentType, string fileName, DateTime modificationDate)`

Comment: Whats is `Stream fileStream` ? Can you help me ?

Comment: If you use an `ExecuteReader` command on either a `SqlCommand` or an `EntityCommand`, like I did in the sample above, then you can access the varbinary as a `Stream` using the `GetStream(0)` call above.


Use that instead of a `byte[]` when calling `RangeFIleStreamResult()`


`GetStream()` doesn't have to retrieve the entire video as a single object, but will then let you access the data like you would a file.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Streams let you manipulate large amounts of data without having to hold it all in memory at one time.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: bigtlb,  Please see it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46811925/element-video-does-not-play-using-rangefilestreamresult